# How to draw a bounded area using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to draw an area bounded by two conditions
1. x>=150
2. x<300

Any ideas ?

I am unfortunately not too familiar with gnuplot

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check `help rectangle`.

```
reset session

set obj 1 rect from first 150, graph 0 to first 300, graph 1 
set obj 1 fc rgb "red" fillstyle solid 0.3

set xrange [0:500]

plot x
```

[image]